# Java, 3D prospective projection

Tags: java, 3d

I'm learning 3D rendering with java and I encountered a weird issue.

I'm able to rotate and display 3D objects to the screen. but when I tried to use prospective projection to show depth, the program freaks out. No errors or anything, but the depth seems to stretch incurability long. I narrowed the problem down to the perspective divide in the projection function.

Can anyone help?

```
public class Renderer extends JPanel{

public Renderer() {
    
}

double angle = 0;
double a;
double f;
double l;
double offSet;

public void update() {
    
    angle += 0.03;
    
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    super.paintComponent(g2d);

    for(Triangle element: MidService.mesh) 
    {

        Vertex v1 = rotateY(element.v1);
        Vertex v2 = rotateY(element.v2);
        Vertex v3 = rotateY(element.v3);

        v1 = projection(v1);
        v2 = projection(v2);
        v3 = projection(v3);
        
        int offSet = (int) (MidService.displayX/2);

        g2d.drawLine(offSet + v1.x, offSet + v1.y, offSet + v2.x, offSet + v2.y);
        g2d.drawLine(offSet + v2.x, offSet + v2.y, offSet + v3.x, offSet + v3.y);
        g2d.drawLine(offSet + v3.x, offSet + v3.y, offSet + v1.x, offSet + v1.y);
        

    }
}

public Vertex projection(Vertex v)
{
    a = MidService.displayY / MidService.displayX;
    f = 1 / (Math.tan(MidService.fieldOfView/2));
    l = MidService.Zfar / (MidService.Zfar - MidService.Znear);
    offSet = MidService.Zfar / (MidService.Zfar - MidService.Znear) * MidService.Znear;
    
    double x = (v.x * a * f);
    double y = (v.y * f);
    double z = (v.z * l - offSet);
    double w = v.z;
    //the if function below caused the issue

    if(w != 0.0) {
        x /= w;
        y /= w;
        z /= w;
    }
    return new Vertex((int)x, (int)y, (int)z);
}


public Vertex rotateY(Vertex v)
{
    double x = v.x * Math.cos(angle) + v.z * Math.sin(angle);
    double y = v.y;
    double z = v.x * (-Math.sin(angle)) + v.z * Math.cos(angle);
    
    return new Vertex((int)x, (int)y, (int)z);
}
```

//-------------------------------------------------------

```
public class MidService {

public static double displayX = 1000;
public static double displayY = 1000;
public static double fieldOfView = 180;
public static double Zfar = 10;
public static double Znear = 1;

public static ArrayList<Triangle> mesh = new ArrayList<>();
```

}
//---------------------------------------------

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Display display = new Display();
    
    MidService.mesh.add(new Triangle(new Vertex(-100, 100, 100),
                                    new Vertex(-100, -100, 100),
                                    new Vertex(100, -100, 100)));
    MidService.mesh.add(new Triangle(new Vertex(-100, 100, 100),
                                    new Vertex(100, -100, 100),
                                    new Vertex(100, 100, 100)));
```

Here's a video of it:[https://youtu.be/bFJLU5c3JE0]

Answer (score 0):

A follow up to the perspective division issue.  It turns out to be the inverse of the difference between camera distance and z coordinate.  So instead of division by z, its 1/(distance - z)

Below is modification for Gaba Miau's matrix multiply function

```
    Vertex Mult(float[][] mat,Vertex v){
    float ver[] = {v.x,v.y,v.z,v.w};
    float ans[] = {0,0,0,0};
    
    for (int i=0;i<mat.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<mat[0].length;j++){
            ans[i] += mat[i][j] * ver[j];
        }
    }
    
    float temp = 100/(500 - v.z);
    if(temp != 0)
    {
        ans[0] *= temp;
        ans[1] *= temp;
        ans[2] *= temp;
    }
    Vertex vans = new Vertex((int)ans[0],(int)ans[1],(int)ans[2]);
    vans.w =(int) ans[3];
    return vans;
}
```

P.S. it's ans[i] += mat[i][j] * ver[j]; in the forloop

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you should be using a graphics API like OpenGL or DirectX, secondly you should be using a math library like GLM that contains all the projection matrix formulas and other stuff. Thirdly, you shouldn't be using int as a datatype to store vertex data.
I made a few changes to your code so it doesn't freak out anymore.
The fov should be in the range(0.001,179.999), never 180, it is recommanded using 90 deg. Also the math function tan takes in radians not deg.

```
package Render;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.sound.midi.MidiDevice;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import Beans.Triangle;
import Beans.Vertex;
import Utilities.MidService;

public class Renderer extends JPanel{
    
    public Renderer() {
        
    }
    
    double angle = 0;
    double a;
    double f;
    double l;
    double offSet;
    
    public void update() {
        
        //angle += 0.03;
        
        repaint();
    }
    float projMat[][]= {
            {1f / ((float)Math.tan(MidService.fieldOfView/2f)),0,0,0},
            {0,1f / ((float)Math.tan(MidService.fieldOfView/2f)),0,0},
            {0,0,MidService.Zfar / (MidService.Zfar - MidService.Znear),1},
            {0,0,-MidService.Zfar* MidService.Znear / (MidService.Zfar - MidService.Znear),0},
    };
    Vertex Mult(float[][] mat,Vertex v){
        float ver[] = {v.x,v.y,v.z,v.w};
        float ans[] = {0,0,0,0};
        for (int i=0;i<mat.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<mat[0].length;j++){
                ans[i] += mat[i][j] * ver[i];
            }
        }
        Vertex vans = new Vertex((int)ans[0],(int)ans[1],(int)ans[2]);
        vans.w =(int) ans[3];
        return vans;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);

        for(Triangle element: MidService.mesh) 
        {

            Vertex v1 = rotateZ(element.v1);
            Vertex v2 = rotateZ(element.v2);
            Vertex v3 = rotateZ(element.v3);

            v1 = rotateY(v1);
            v2 = rotateY(v2);
            v3 = rotateY(v3);

            v1 = Mult(projMat,v1);
            v2 = Mult(projMat,v2);
            v3 = Mult(projMat,v3);
            
            int offSet = (int) (MidService.displayX/2);
            
            g2d.drawLine(offSet + (int)v1.x, offSet + (int)v1.y, offSet + (int)v2.x, offSet + (int)v2.y);
            g2d.drawLine(offSet + (int)v2.x, offSet + (int)v2.y, offSet + (int)v3.x, offSet + (int)v3.y);
            g2d.drawLine(offSet + (int)v3.x, offSet + (int)v3.y, offSet + (int)v1.x, offSet + (int)v1.y);
            

        }
    }
    
    public Vertex projection(Vertex v)
    {
        a = MidService.displayY / MidService.displayX;
        f = 1 / (Math.tan(MidService.fieldOfView/2));
        l = MidService.Zfar / (MidService.Zfar - MidService.Znear);
        offSet = MidService.Zfar / (MidService.Zfar - MidService.Znear) * MidService.Znear;
        
        double x = (v.x * a * f);
        double y = (v.y * f);
        double z = (v.z * l - offSet);
        double w = v.z;
        
        if(w != 0.0) {
            x /= w;
            y /= w;
            z /= w;
        }
        return new Vertex((int)x, (int)y, (int)z);
    }
    
    
    public Vertex rotateY(Vertex v)
    {
        double x = v.x * Math.cos(angle) + v.z * Math.sin(angle);
        double y = v.y;
        double z = v.x * (-Math.sin(angle)) + v.z * Math.cos(angle);
        
        return new Vertex((int)x, (int)y, (int)z);
    }
    
    public Vertex rotateZ(Vertex v)
    {
        double x = v.x * Math.cos(angle) + v.y * (-Math.sin(angle));
        double y = v.x * Math.sin(angle) + v.y * Math.cos(angle);
        double z = v.z;
        
        return new Vertex((int)x, (int)y, (int)z);
    }

}
```

Here is the MidService class

```
package Utilities;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Beans.Triangle;

public class MidService {

public static float displayX = 1000;
public static float displayY = 1000f;
public static float fieldOfView = 3.14f/2f;
public static float Zfar = 100f;
public static float Znear = 0.1f;

public static ArrayList<Triangle> mesh = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

And Vertex

```
package Beans;

public class Vertex {
    
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
    public float w = 1;
    
    public Vertex(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!!!  I'm learning 3D rendering myself through Youtube, and I'm trying to understand the most basic ideas of it first.  Thank you very much for your response.  But unfortunately the code above takes us back to square one.  It renders in orthographic view, and I'm trying to show depth.  And the perspective divide brings us the same problem.